# What is the alternative to python requests package to use REST API's in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, python-requests, pyspark

Newbie to python and pyspark.

I have used python's request package to retrieve data from applications that has REST API through 'get' method which provides response as json data, which is then read into pandas dataframe.

I'm trying to migrate the code for Spark with Pyspark now.

Wondering if there is any alternative to python requests package for spark.

Or any way that has to be followed.

I can still do with existing code of python and change the  pandas dataframe that captures the data into pyspark dataframe, but i believe that will not be efficient.

Need some suggestions on how to use rest api of an application in Pyspark.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can map requests on to the RDD's so that it can distribute the `GET`/`POST` mechanism